# MongoDB Filter data points within an interval

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a database query that selects all documents having a timestamp field (tmp) falling in a certain range, like so

```
{ tmp: { '$gte': 1411929000000, '$lte': 1419010200000 } }
```

This query returns a large number of records, say 10000.

Objective: 
To fetch documents in the **same interval range**, *but separated by say (1 hour timestamp) interval in between* hence reduce the number of records that is fetched.

Is there a way of doing this entirely using MongoDB query system?

Due to NDA I can not show the code, but it basically contains Stock Exchange data (say in 1 minute interval). And the objective is to send a sample of these data between two endpoints (time). But the thing is, the client can ask for a 5 minute interval data or 10 min, or 1 hour etc, so from these 1 minute interval data I need to sample and send only the relevant ones. Hope that makes it more clear.

Any comments would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to accomplish your objective directly, but you can do something very close. Given a range of time `[s, t]` and a separation `p`, you're looking for approximately `(t - s) / p` documents evenly spread over the range, to give a "zoomed-out" sense of the data. Pick `x`, ideally small compared to `p`, large enough to contain documents but small enough not to contain very many, and look for documents within an interval of width `x` around evenly spaced points separated by `p`. You can do this with a single `$or` query or with a series of queries. For example, simplifying using integers instead of dates, if I have a field `score` with values in the range `[0, 50]` and want a resolution of `p = 10`, I'll look at intervals of width  `x = 1` around points separated by 10:

```
db.test.find({ "$or" : [
    { "score" : { "$gte" : 0, "$lte" : 1 } },
    { "score" : { "$gte" : 9, "$lte" : 11 } },
    { "score" : { "$gte" : 19, "$lte" : 21 } },
    { "score" : { "$gte" : 29, "$lte" : 31 } },
    { "score" : { "$gte" : 39, "$lte" : 41 } },
    { "score" : { "$gte" : 49, "$lte" : 50 } },
] })
```

You could break this into 6 (`(t - s) / p + 1`) queries and limit 1 result in each query, alternatively.

There are a couple of other higher-level ways to approach your problem. I'd suggest looking at the following two schema design articles from the MongoDB Manual:

- [Pre-Aggregated Reports](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/)
- [Hierarchical Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/hierarchical-aggregation/)

Comment: Thank you. Although the example you provided may not be as useful to me, but it looks like I will find something important and useful in the links on Aggregation.